# Cross vocabulary relationship

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have multiple vocabularies:

1. Year Model
2. Origin
3. Make
4. Model
5. Variants

Year Model:

- 2016
- 2015
- ...
- 2002
- 2001

Origin:

- American
- Asian
- European
- Japanese

Make:

- Audi
- BMW
- Chrysler
- Dodge
- Ford
- Ferrari
- ...
- Hyundai
- Mitsubishi
- Subaru
- Toyota
- Volvo

Model:

- R8
- Fortuner
- Montero Sports
- XC90
- Forester
- 116i

Variants:

- FSI Quattro 4.2L Gas 6Spd MT AWD
- G 2.5L Diesel MT 4x2
- GLX 2.5L Diesel MT 4x2 (Non-VGT)
- X 2.0L Gas AT AWD

What I wanted is for example I am going to select `American` as origin then I wanted the `Make` vocabulary to only display the `make/brand` under American. I tried several contrib modules like Term Relations, Taxonomy Set Lineage, Combined Termref but I cannot achieved what I want (maybe I overlooked the contrib modules I tried). Is there a way that I can specify the relationship between terms of different vocabulary.

Here is my thought:

```
Vocal Origin   - American
               - European
               - Asian
               - Japanese

Vocab Make     - Ford (Parent Term: American)
               - Toyota (Parent Term: Japanese)
               - Audi (Parent Term: European)

Vocab Model    - Fortuner (Parent Term: Toyota)
               - Mustang (Parent Term: Ford)
               - A1 (Parent Term Term: Audi)

Vocab Variants - Turbo FSI 1.4L Gas S-Tronic (Parent Term: A1)
               - G 2.5L Diesel MT 4x2 (Parent Term: Fortuner)
               - EcoBoost Premium 2.3L Gas AT (Parent Term: Mustang)
```

I know that I this is pretty simple using parent-child terms in a single vocabulary but the issue with this solution is the editors will not be able to easily add new items as that could be confusing to them. Doing in a separate vocabulary will allow them to easily manage the terms.

Comment: Will adding term reference field to you vocabulary field help?

Comment: @VishalKumar that was actually what I did and have a custom menu callback to query based on the term reference and apply the result in the other dropdown field.